# AWS use local area IP or public one to network apps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mongodb

I have a web server with a separate database server in this case a MongoDB, both are hosted on EC2, but when connecting my webserver to my database server is it best to use the public IP address or the private local one (10.*.*.*).

I'd like to have the best performance and security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the private IP address for that. The public IP should only be used for public-facing services, and your Mongo is not such a service.

Comment: Are there any benifits giving it an CNAME? Like then it would be db.example.com, or is that just a waste of DNS lookups just to make my app configure easier to read too... I'm taking your answer as my solution, but I was curious if having a CNAME could make it easier if I wanted to make another server write to the DB too.

Comment: It is possible to build your own private DNS on a private domain (or even something like 'internal.example.com') to make this easier too, and it should scale up well should the need arise.